# Assign value to a nested list based on conditions specified by keys

Tags: python, dictionary

## Problem

I have a nested dictionary that looks like the following. Now I am trying to find an **elegant** way to assign value to replace 0's based on value of `b` and `f`.

```
{
    (a1, b1): {
        c1: {
            (d1, f1): 0, 
            (d2, f2): 0
        }
    },
    (a2, b2): {
        c2: {
            (d3, f3): 0
        }
    }
}
```

## What I Have Done

I know I could use three loops to check whether conditions are met, but it is not very elegant and efficient either.

Comment: Providing the _not very elegant and efficient_ code can help us help you. Don't forget to provide [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: What makes you think that it's neither elegant nor efficient to use loops here? If you are in fact touching all of the leaf items, loops will be at least as efficient as any other method, and there's nothing necessarily inelegant about loops when they're efficient.